# Heuristics, tricks, and hacks in symbolic math

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

*Mathematica* sometimes fails to compute symbolic solutions when posed in the direct or obvious code, but *succeeds* when the same fundamental problem is posed in a slightly different way, or when assumptions are made explicit, or other tricks and hacks.

Example (v. 11.3):

```
Integrate[
 ((I E^(I t) + 2 I E^(I x)) PolyLog[2, 1 - E^(I (t - x))])/(E^(I (t + 2 x))), 
 x]
```

fails to integrate, but if it is split into the two component integrals in the natural way, it succeeds.  (The two component answers can be added and then `FullSimplify`ed.)

As a result, there must be cases where users have given up in frustration when the proper hack or trick would have solved their problem.

As a service to the community (and for my own use), I'd like to collect in one place examples of such tricks and hacks that have yielded symbolic solutions when the direct or "obvious" approach failed.

(I'm not interested in *numerical* hacks... as these are of a fundamentally different sort.)

Some of the tricks I've come across include:

- expressing constraints in novel ways
- Expanding a complex function into a sum of simpler functions and integrating them individually
- solving a "simpler" integral symbolically and then taking the limit of some variable to the desired value
- forcing a "smart" change of variables
- breaking an integral into component parts (as above)

Again, I'd like to limit consideration to *symbolic* computational mathematics, so I expect most answers will involve `Integrate`, `D`, `Solve`, `DSolve`, `Simplify`, and such.  As a mild request, I think we would all best profit from *minimal* problems that require a particular hack.

*Mathematica*'s symbolic manipulation is an extraordinary tool, but like all complex tools, its power and applicability is enhanced with the user knows how best to use it... and that sometimes includes non-obvious heuristics and hacks.

Comment: The workaround that you described can be done by `Simplify[Integrate[#, x] & /@ Expand[f[x]]]` Mapping `Integrate` over `Plus` will take care of doing multiple integrals and summing the results.

Comment: Excellent example!  Post it as an answer!  (Perhaps make a new minimal example, to keep things interesting.)

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2257849).

Answer (score 14):

To calculate

```
Integrate[ArcTan[a*Sqrt[1 - k^2*Sin[z]^2]]/Sqrt[1 - k^2*Sin[z]^2], {z, 0,Pi/2}]
```

do *differentiation under the integral* with respect to the parameter a

```
D[ArcTan[a*Sqrt[1 - k^2*Sin[z]^2]]/Sqrt[1 - k^2*Sin[z]^2], a]
```

and integrate over z :

```
Integrate[1/(1 + a^2 - a^2*k^2*Sin[z]^2), z]
(* ArcTanh[(Sqrt[-1 + a^2*(-1 + k^2)]*Tan[z])/Sqrt[1 + a^2]]/
(Sqrt[1 + a^2]*Sqrt[-1 + a^2*(-1 + k^2)])*)
```

Take the minus out of the square roots to get :

```
ArcTan[(Sqrt[1 + a^2*(1 - k^2)]*Tan[z])/Sqrt[1 + a^2]]/
(Sqrt[1 + a^2]*Sqrt[1 + a^2*(1 - k^2)])
```

Insertion of the limits z = Pi/2 and z = 0 gives

```
Pi/(2*(Sqrt[1 + a^2]*Sqrt[1 + a^2*(1 - k^2)]))
```

which may then be integrated to reverse the initial differentiation :

```
Integrate[Pi/(2*(Sqrt[1 + a^2]*Sqrt[1 + a^2*(1 - k^2)])), a]
(* (Pi*EllipticF[ArcSin[a*Sqrt[-1 + k^2]], 1/(1 - k^2)])/(2*
Sqrt[-1 + k^2]) *)
```

To shape this into a nicer form take again the minus out of the square roots to get :

```
(Pi*EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[a*Sqrt[1 - k^2]], 1/(1 - k^2)])/(I*2*Sqrt[1 - k^2])
```

With two subsequent transformations  for EllipticF like (https://dlmf.nist.gov 19.7.7 and 19.7.5)

```
EllipticF[I zz, kk^2] -> I EllipticF[ArcTan[Sinh[zz]], 1 - kk^2]
```

and

```
EllipticF[zz, -kk] -> EllipticF[ArcTan[Sqrt[1 + kk]*Tan[zz]], kk/(1 + kk)]/Sqrt[1 + kk]
```

we obtain the beautiful result of the original integral

```
Pi/2*EllipticF[ArcTan[a], k^2]
```

This procedure helped me calculating many integrals.

Comment: Excellent... just what I'm seeking.  And so elegant!  Thanks.  (+1).

Comment: Since differentiating under the integral sign is often but not always valid, one should always find a way to check such answers.

Answer (score 12):

If [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) returns unevaluated, expand the integrand (into a sum of simpler functions) and map `Integrate` onto the expanded expression. If the term-by-term integrations are successful, the evaluated expression will be the original integral.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

f[x_, t_] := ((I E^(I t) + 2 I E^(I x)) PolyLog[2, 
      1 - E^(I (t - x))])/(E^(I (t + 2 x)));
```

Direct integration returns unevaluated

```
Integrate[f[x, t], x]
```

[image]

Integrating the expanded expression term-by-term

```
int[x_, t_] = Simplify[Integrate[#, x] & /@ Expand[f[x, t]]]

(* 1/8 E^(-2 I (t + x)) (E^(2 I t) + 20 E^(I (t + x)) - 
   2 E^(2 I t) Log[E^(I (t - x))] - 20 E^(I (t + x)) Log[E^(I (t - x))] - 
   10 E^(2 I x) Log[E^(I (t - x))]^2 - 
   20 E^(2 I x) Log[E^(I (t - x))] Log[1 - E^(I (-t + x))] + 
   20 E^(2 I x) PolyLog[2, E^(I (-t + x))] - 
   4 E^(I t) (E^(I t) + 4 E^(I x)) PolyLog[2, 1 - E^(I (t - x))]) *)
```

Verifying that this result is a valid antiderivative of the original integrand

```
D[int[x, t], x] == f[x, t] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Good start (+1).  Let's hope for lots of more examples... including from differential equations and other domains.  (I'd love to see another *class* of function where the illustrated problem occurs too.)

Answer (score 10):

A way to get sometimes unexpected results :

The following integral is ' easy'

```
Integrate[Log[1 - x]/(1 - x), x]
(* (-(1/2))*Log[1 - x]^2 *)
```

Now write explicitly the geometric series

```
Sum[x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}]
(* 1/(1 - x) *)
```

inside the integral

```
(-(1/2))*Log[1 - x]^2 = Integrate[Log[1 - x]/(1 - x), x] = 
Integrate[Sum[x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}] Log[1 - x], x],
```

exchange integral and sum

```
Sum[Integrate[x^k Log[1 - x], x], {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

and let  Mathematica do the  the integral

```
Sum[(x^(1 + k)*(x*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 + k, 3 + k, x] + (2 + k)*Log[1 - x]))/
 ((1 + k)*(2 + k)), {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

The Hypergeometric can be simplified

```
Sum[(Beta[x, 2 + k, 0] + x^(1 + k)*Log[1 - x])/(1 + k), {k, 0, Infinity}] = 
Sum[Beta[x, 2 + k, 0]/(1 + k), {k, 0, Infinity}] + 
Log[1 - x])*Sum[(x^k)/k, {k, 1, Infinity}] = 
Sum[Beta[x, 2 + k, 0]/(1 + k), {k, 0, Infinity}] - Log[1 - x]^2
```

So finally

```
Sum[Beta[x, k + 1 , 0]/k, {k, 1, Infinity}] = (1/2)*Log[1 - x]^2
```

A nice closed form...

**Edit:**

Another example for this technique is

```
Integrate[E^(-a*x^n)/(1 - b*E^(-c*x^n)), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

Mathematica cannot calculate this integral. Replace the 'geometric factor' with

```
Sum[b^k* E^(-c*k*x^n), {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

and exchange integral and sum

```
Sum[(b^k*Gamma[1 + 1/n])/(a + c*k)^n^(-1), {k, 0, Infinity}]
(* (Gamma[(1 + n)/n]*HurwitzLerchPhi[b, 1/n, a/c])/c^n^(-1) *)
```

valid for b < 1.

Comment: Interesting... but can you show an "unsolvable" problem that becomes solvable using this technique?

Comment: Mathematica does not solve `Sum[Beta[x, k + 1 , 0]/k, {k, 1, Infinity}]`

Comment: Ah... that wasn't clear to me.  So thanks!  (+1)

Answer (score 5):

**Assuming that as stated in the subject line, the question is about "symbolic math" in general and not just integration:**

To find a closed-form representation of a recursive function definition, a typical approach is to generate a sequence from the recursion and then use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) on the sequence.

```
f[1] = a*x + b;

f[n_Integer?Positive] := f[n] =
  Integrate[c*x^k*f[n - 1], x] // Simplify

seq = f /@ Range[6]

(* {b + a x, c x^(1 + k) (b/(1 + k) + (a x)/(2 + k)), 
 1/2 c^2 x^(2 + 2 k) (b/(1 + k)^2 + (2 a x)/(6 + 7 k + 2 k^2)), 
 1/6 c^3 x^(3 + 3 k) (b/(1 + k)^3 + (6 a x)/(24 + 46 k + 29 k^2 + 6 k^3)), 
 1/24 c^4 x^(
  4 + 4 k) (b/(1 + k)^4 + (24 a x)/((5 + 4 k) (24 + 46 k + 29 k^2 + 6 k^3))), 
 1/120 c^5 x^(
  5 + 5 k) (b/(1 + k)^5 + (
    120 a x)/((5 + 4 k) (6 + 5 k) (24 + 46 k + 29 k^2 + 6 k^3)))} *)
```

However, with more complicated functions such as this, `FindSequenceFunction` returns unevaluated.

```
FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // Short[#, 3] &
```

[image]

To workaround this, use `FindSequenceFunction` on the separate parts of the sequence

```
(f2[n_, x_] = Total[FindSequenceFunction[#, n] & /@
     Transpose[List @@@ (seq // Expand)]] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify)//TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Verifying the equivalence of `f` (recursive) and `f2` (closed-form) for positive integer values of `n`

```
And @@ (Table[f[n] == f2[n, x] // FullSimplify, {n, 1, 30}])

(* True *)
```

However, note that the closed-form definition,`f2`, is not limited to positive integer values of `n`.

```
f2[3.2, 1.7] /. {a -> 0.25, b -> 1.5, c -> 1.75, k -> 0.5}

(* 5.61395 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the place I have run into this most is with Fourier transforms. For example, if we try to calculate the Fourier transform of Sin[t] directly from the definition

```
Integrate[Sin[t] Exp[I w t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

we get a message that the integral does not converge on {-Infinity, Infinity}. But we can take this transform easily using the built-in function

```
FourierTransform[Sin[t], t, w]
```

which gives the answer as a sum of two delta functions (as we may have been taught in school).