# Asymptotic[] Doesn't Actually Compute

Tags: scripting, asymptotics

I ran into this problem while studying the asymptotic behavior of a probability distribution function called tao2. It computes correctly at positive infinity but doesn't actually compute at negative infinity. Instead, Mathematica simply spits out the input. Is there any way to fix this?
[image]

For reference,

```
tao2 = (2*(-(1/4)/E^(2*t^2)+Pi/8-((1/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*t)/E^t^2+(1/4)*Pi*Erf[t]
  -((1/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*t*Erf[t])/E^t^2+(1/8)*Pi*Erf[t]^2))/Pi
```

**Update 1**: Asymptotic[] works when I separate tau2 into two parts and compute separately (one contains all terms involving the error function, another contains all other terms). However, these two parts add up to 0, while I expect to see E^(-2*t^2)/t^2 times some constant.

**Update 2**: As Bob Hanlon suggested, the expanded form of the tao function is indeed more suitable for computation. However, when using both the original form and the expanded form on a tester function (called tao1), the two methods produce different results.
[image]
Here

```
tao1 = (1/2)*(1+Erf[t])
```

Comment: Please provide the Mathematica code (InputForm) for the definition of `tao2` that can be copy and pasted.

Comment: Use either `Limit[tao2, t -> -Infinity]` or `Series[tao2, {t, -Infinity, 1}] // Normal` Both evaluate to `0`

Comment: Interestingly, `Asymptotic[FullSimplify@tao2, t -> -Infinity]` seems to work.

Comment: @thorimur I just tried that but it gave the (simplified) expression of tau2. Do you mind sharing the result you got?

Comment: Oh, I see. yes, you're right, that's simply tau2 in a different form  very weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tao2 = (2*(-(1/4)/E^(2*t^2) + 
       Pi/8 - ((1/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*t)/E^t^2 + (1/4)*Pi*Erf[t] - 
        ((1/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*t*Erf[t])/E^t^2 + (1/8)*Pi*Erf[t]^2))/Pi;
```

Expanding `tao2` and calculating the `Asymptotic` for each term

```
Asymptotic[#, t -> -Infinity] & /@ (tao2 // Expand)

(* -(E^(-2 t^2)/(2 π)) *)

Limit[%, t -> -Infinity]

(* 0 *)
```

**EDIT:** Similarly, for the other side

```
Asymptotic[#, t -> Infinity] & /@ (tao2 // Expand)

(* 1 - E^(-2 t^2)/(2 π) - (E^-t^2 t)/Sqrt[π] *)

Limit[%, t -> Infinity]

(* 1 *)
```

**EDIT 2:** For the `tao1` example:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

tao1 = (1/2)*(1 + Erf[t]);

Asymptotic[tao1, t -> -Infinity]

(* -(E^-t^2/(2 Sqrt[π] t)) *)

Asymptotic[#, t -> -Infinity] & /@ (tao1 // Expand)

(* 0 *)
```

To get the same result mapping onto the expanded  expression, the option [`SeriesTermGoal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesTermGoal.html) is needed.

```
Asymptotic[#, t -> -Infinity, SeriesTermGoal -> 2] & /@ 
 (tao1 // Expand)

(* -(E^-t^2/(2 Sqrt[π] t)) *)

Limit[%, t -> -Infinity]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you mind sharing the reasoning behind it, i.e. why the expanded form is more suitable for computation in this case?

Comment: `Expand` produces an expression with the `Head`  `Plus`. The individual terms are simpler and easier for `Asymptotic` to process. Mapping onto the `Plus` automatically sums the individually processed terms. This is analogous to doing complicated [`integrations`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245412/9362) that don't directly evaluate with `Integrate[#, {x, x0, xf}] & /@ (expr // Expand)`

Comment: That really helps. Thanks so much!

Comment: On a side note, I tried both the original form and with Expand on a tester function, but they different output (as shown in the modified question prompt). Should we expect them to be the same?