# Integrals that cannot be solved with a direct approach

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm collecting problems for which the basic or direct approach in *Mathematica* (v. 13 or later) does not work, but requires some trick or mathematical insight.  I'd like to start with integration.

[For instance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79152/finding-simplifying-substitutions-for-an-integral-involving-limits-and-integrand),

```
int = Integrate[
Sqrt[Log[9-x]]/(Sqrt[Log[9-x]]+ Sqrt[Log[3+x]]), 
{x,2,4}]
```

does not evaluate, but

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[int, y, y == x - 3];

Activate[%]
```

gives the correct answer.  Again, mere "direct button pushing" does not work;  the user must see and exploit mathematical knowledge.

I want my students to learn these special tricks and insights, and the more examples I have the better.

I think examples here would be of great use to our community (and to WRI as it refines its symbolic algorithms).

Comment: Not sure I understand the difference with the previous post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245399/heuristics-tricks-and-hacks-in-symbolic-math

Comment: Entirely different.  No relation whatsoever.  The previous posting is about integrals that ***cannot be solved*** directly, and the length of solution is irrelevant.  The posting here is about integrals that ***CAN be solved*** directly and the length of the solution is essential.  What do you see as the similarity between the questions?  Please explain.

Comment: The comment above is not on your post about the length of integrals. The link I gave is for a question you asked in 2021 which was more general but included this question. I mainly left the link as a reference to a related post. I have a vague memory of another post that listed some methods but I can not find it

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The following integral returns unevaluated

```
Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/x])^x, {t, 0, ∞}]]
```

[image]

Evaluating for specific integer values of `x`

```
seq = Integrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/#])^#, {t, 0, ∞}] & /@ Range[7]

(* {1, 3, 11/2, 25/3, 137/12, 147/10, 363/20} *)
```

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize from the sequence -- to include for non-integer values of `x`

```
int[x_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, x] // FullSimplify

(* x HarmonicNumber[x] *)
```

Verifying the result by comparing with numerical integration

```
intN[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/x])^x, {t, 0, ∞}]

Plot[{int[x], intN[x]}, {x, 0, 1000},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Exact", "Numeric"}, {.75, .3}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, int})]
```

[image]

Comment: I was not aware of the following bug: `Integrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/x])^x /. x -> 1.5, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]` has a do not converge error but  using `x/.->3/2` Mathematica finds an exact result.

Comment: @userrandrand - even worse, `Integrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/x])^x /. x -> 1.5, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}, GenerateConditions -> True]` evaluates to an imaginary number.

Comment: I checked wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i2d=true&i=4.71238898038469) and the imaginary number is probably $3 \pi /2 $ or a more complicated number related to zeta.

Comment: With `x->2.4` and `GenerateConditions -> True` it outputs a complex number where the imaginary part has practically all of the digits of $ 2.4\pi$. Not sure what mathematica is doing with the real part.

Comment: Sorry maybe last comment. With `AsymptoticIntegrate[1 - (1 - Exp[-t/x])^x /. x -> 3/2, {t, 0, y}, y -> Infinity]` a $3\pi/2$ also appears. Also, changing the lower boundary from 0 to 1 with ` /. x ->3/2` the $i3\pi/2$ appears but it is canceled exactly by an $\arcsin$ term. Maybe the source of the error is somewhere around there.

Comment: Interesting example ($+1$).  I'm a bit concerned about using FindSequenceFunction and then interpolating.  I do hope to find other examples....  Thanks!

Comment: I found that v 13.0 can calculate the *indefinite* integral, $$t-\frac{\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{x}}\right)^x \left(e^{t/x}-1\right) \,
   _2F_1\left(1,1;1-x;e^{t/x}\right)}{\log (e)}$$ and then we can simply evaluate at $\infty$ and $0$.